# primefaces datatable selection attribute always populating first row for the first time

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

```
 Hello Guys,  

<h:form id="targetsMenuPanelForm">  
<p:commandButton id="cancel" ajax="false" process="@this" value="Cancel" 
    action="#{myMenuTabsBean.cancel}" styleClass="uta-button button-red"  />

<p:commandButton id="save" process="@form" action="#{myMenuTabsBean.save}"  
    update="@form" value="Save" />  
<p:commandButton id="new" action="#{myBackingbean.addEmptyRow}"  
     process="@this" update="myTable" value="New" />  
<p:commandButton id="delete" value="Delete"  
     action="#{myBackingbean.deleteRow}" process="@form" update="@form" />  

<p:dataTable id="myTable" value="#{myBackingbean.myDataModel}"  
   var="myList" selection="#{myBackingbean.selectedRows}">
    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" id="select" />
    <p:column id="namecol" headerText="Name">
       <p:inputText id="name" value="#{myList.targetName}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column id="typecol" headerText="Type">  
       <p:selectOneMenu id="types" value="#{myList.type}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Direct Dial" itemValue="DirectDial" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="Private Wire" itemValue="PrivateWire" />
   </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:column>  
  </p:dataTable>  
  </h:form>
```

The above code is my Xhtml. New button adds an empty row to the list every time
    it is  clicked.

Now assume I added two empty rows by clicking on new button twice. Now I have populated the two rows with some data and checked the second row checkbox/selected row and clicked on save button which saves this second row into db.

The problem is always the first row is being populated into the array mapped
    to the selection attribute of the data table and is being saved into db.

Assume If i keep first row empty and populate second row and check/select second
    row and try to save it, application throws an error to enter name and now the
    first row is selected not the second row. If i un check/un select first row and
    select/check second row and try to save every thing goes well now.

Could any one help me to resolve this...thanks in advance guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should post your backing bean and error messages.
Because it's no problem with your page code.

What's more,I don't quite get what do you intend to do with the code.
Are you going to use the dataTable as a buffer and save the selected record into DB?
If so,try this:

(Page is exact the same as yours)
**myBackingbean.java**：

```
private DataModel myDataModel;
private List<myData> temp=new ArrayList<>();
private myData[] selectedRows=new myData[100];
private int count=0;
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    temp=new ArrayList<>();
    count=0;
    myDataModel=new DataModel();
}
public void addEmptyRow(){
    temp.add(new myData("targetName"+count,"type"+count++));
    myDataModel=new DataModel(temp);
}
public void deleteRow(){
    for(myData m:selectedRows){
        temp.remove(m);
    }
    myDataModel=new DataModel(temp);
}
//getters and setters below...
```

**myMenuTabsBean.java**：

```
private List<myData> savedData = new ArrayList<>();

public void cancel() {
    myBackingbean myBean = (myBackingbean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext().getELResolver().getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), null, "myBackingbean");
    DataModel myData = new DataModel();
    myBean.setMyDataModel(myData);
    myBean.init();
}

public void save() {
    myBackingbean myBean = (myBackingbean) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext().getELResolver().getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(), null, "myBackingbean");
    myData[] my = myBean.getSelectedRows();
    for (myData m : my) {
        savedData.add(m);  //Add to List instead of DB for simplicity.
    }
    printSavedData();
    cancel();
}

public void printSavedData() {  //print saved data to see if the data is saved.
    for (int i = 0; i < savedData.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(savedData.get(i).getTargetName() + ":" + savedData.get(i).getType());
    }
}
```

Lastly, why do you write `save()` and `cancel()` in `myMenuTabsBean` instead of `myBackingbean`?  Isn't that more complex? Is there other concern about this?

Comment: Thanks you very much for the reply and sorry for the delay in acknowledging that. Earlier I haven't observed the usage of nested forms in the page since I was not the actual developer(actually this page was included in another page which has a master form). I have removed nested forms and removed unnecessary ajax calls. Now every thing works fine. As you said the xhtml is fine hence accepting the answer.